# I'm not able to process set of record through awk script

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to process set of records but I'm not able to get expected output this set of code is not able to print 12 column(It is empty).
Data test.txt

```
"B64NN2",163934,"ALLPMR",22193625,G,"XYX, Test Surgery","31 Orwell Road","TTP","","IP11 7DD","IP11 7DD",,"DMB0406C","2011-09-12","2011-11-02"
"B6PPL1",215969,"ALLPMR",22192331,G,"KBC Medical Test","Open Close","JJK  Cardiff","South Glamorgan","CF15 8DZ","CF15 8DZ",,"DMB4001B","2011-09-12","2013-08-01"


awk  'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," }  { nf=0; delete f; while ( match($0,/([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")/) ) { f[++nf] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH); };  print f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6],f[7],f[8],f[9],f[11],f[12],f[13],f[14],f[15] }' test.txt
```

Output

```
"B64NN2",163934,"ALLPMR",22193625,G,"XYX, Test Surgery","31 Orwell Road","TTP","","IP11 7DD","DMB0406C","2011-09-12","2011-11-02"
    "B6PPL1",215969,"ALLPMR",22192331,G,"KBC Medical Test","Open Close","JJK  Cardiff","South Glamorgan","CF15 8DZ","DMB4001B","2011-09-12","2013-08-01"
```

But output should be like this

```
"B64NN2",163934,"ALLPMR",22193625,G,"XYX, Test Surgery","31 Orwell Road","TTP","","IP11 7DD",,"DMB0406C","2011-09-12","2011-11-02"
        "B6PPL1",215969,"ALLPMR",22192331,G,"KBC Medical Test","Open Close","JJK  Cardiff","South Glamorgan","CF15 8DZ",,"DMB4001B","2011-09-12","2013-08-01"
```

any idea.

Comment: What is the difference between input and expected output? Some repeated fields?

Comment: @Birei thanks 4 ur reply could u check 12 column(input) in  output(12 column should be after 10 in output but I'm not able print).

Comment: Have you upgraded your awk version yet? Why do we need to see an example with double-digits columns - couldn't you show us an example with, say, 5 columns to make our lives a bit easier?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you something obvious, to use a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser to parse [csv](/questions/tagged/csv), instead of counting double quotes and commas. Here you have an example with [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
import csv 
import sys 

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in csvreader:
        newrow = row[0:10]
        newrow.extend(row[11:])
        csvwriter.writerow(newrow)
```

You can run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

That removes the 11th field and keeps the empty one:

```
"B64NN2","163934","ALLPMR","22193625","G","XYX, Test Surgery","31 Orwell Road","TTP","","IP11 7DD","","DMB0406C","2011-09-12","2011-11-02"
"B6PPL1","215969","ALLPMR","22192331","G","KBC Medical Test","Open Close","JJK  Cardiff","South Glamorgan","CF15 8DZ","","DMB4001B","2011-09-12","2013-08-01"
```

Comment: Is It not possible through awk script?

Comment: @akhileshchand: Of course it is possible, but you will have to work harder, because you don't know how many commas there will be inside fields (changing the position). And I'm pretty sure it will be more fragile than a solution with a decent parser.

Comment: @Birei Using FPAT in gawk is pretty good at parsing csvs, I don't think it handles embedded newlines too well but that shouldn't matter for OP.